# MySQL Replace old ID with new one based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe my way of thought is wrong, so first off I will try to explain the situation in words.
I have a Database with about 40000 Titles, some of them are related to each other. This Relations are saved in a different database in a simple a b type manner. The problem is that the system was changed so there is a special row in the main database which contains the old id. And the b value is also the old id... However now I want to replace the b value with the new auto increment id given by the database for all the entries in the relations table. So I thought that I need to create a new table, copy the contents but replacing the b value with the new id...

```
CREATE TABLE list_relations_new LIKE list_listitem_relations; 
INSERT list_relations_new
SELECT lr.a, li.id, lr.typeID
FROM list_listitems li
LEFT JOIN list_listitem_relations lr
ON li.oldID = lr.b
```

Executing this query doesn't give any errors, but also doesn't even create a new table? I hope somebody can help me to sort this out...

Comment: If you want it to assign auto-increment IDs in the new table, you have to leave out the ID field in the `INSERT`, or assign `NULL` to it.

Comment: Could you show the schema for all the old and new tables? Also give some sample old data and the expected results in the new table.

Comment: Thanks the tipp with the NULL worked like a charm.